# use label inside the @html.textbox - ASP.NET RAZOR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, textbox, label

I have an `@html.textBox` and I am woundering if I can define Label inside rather then using separate `@html.label` tag ...

many thanks

### Textbox

```
  @Html.TextBox("Input_AvailableMark_Element", null, new { id = @item.ElementID + "_AM", @class = "ElementAvailableMarks k-grid-input k-textbox_3" })
```

### Label

```
    @Html.Label("AvailableMark", null, new {@class ="inputTextLabel_Custom_1" })
```

Comment: What do you mean "define label inside"? Your question isn't clear. Please explain clearly what you're trying to achieve - maybe some example output would help.

Comment: @AntP, I think he wants to write just one line of code instead of two (one for the label and another for the textbox). `@Html.EditorFor` would work...

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can think of to do that is with usage of placeholder attribute:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SomeProperty, new { placeholder = Model.SomeProperty })
```

I'm assuming you are using DataAnnotations for your models. So for example if you want the Display attribute value to be in your placeholder then you need to write this extension method to fetch data annotation DISPLAY attribute:

```
public static class GetAttributeExtension
{
    public static string GetDisplayName<TModel, TValue>(this TModel model, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        return GetDisplayName(expression);
    }

    public static string GetDisplayName<TModel, TValue>(Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        var propertyName = ((MemberExpression)expression.Body).Member.Name;
        return typeof(TModel).GetAttribute<DisplayAttribute>(propertyName).Name;
    }
}
```

And then you can do something like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SomeProperty, new { placeholder = Model.GetDisplayName(m => m.SomeProperty) })
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what browsers you need to support, the easiest option is as @Marko suggests, add the placeholder attribute.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

However, if you need to support non-HTML5 compliant browsers, this will not work. There are some javascript libraries that will do this behavior for you
http://www.wduffy.co.uk/jLabel/

I have used jLabel before and it works pretty well, but is not without its problems.